# Open project in vagrant with phpstorm

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm

I have installed vagrant in a windows machine. And inside vagrant 
I have a php project.

Is there a way to open this project with phpstorm without synced folders?

Comment: no - if you're not sharing the folder from the VM with the php project, there's no way your host machine will know about it and you can't open it. the other solution would be to install phpstorm on the VM then

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Vagrant+Support+in+PhpStorm